# Escaping mysql quotes in bash script

Tags: mysql, bash, escaping, vagrant

I am trying to execute a script during Vagrant provision that executes some queries on the database to allow root login from any host, create the application database and create the application user, like this:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

sudo bash  << EOF

export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

MYSQL_ROOT_PASS='mySecretPass'
MYSQL_APP_PASS='appSecretPass'

mysql --user='root' --password='${MYSQL_ROOT_PASS}' <<QUERY
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '${MYSQL_ROOT_PASS}';
CREATE DATABASE appdb DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 DEFAULT COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON apdb.* to 'appuser'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '${MYSQL_APP_PASS}';
QUERY


EOF
```

But when I execute above I get the error:

`ERROR 1133 (42000) at line 1: Can't find any matching row in the user table`

I don't quite get how the escaping now works within bash and mysql. I have been messing around with `eval` instead of here documents and some mixed up escaping between " and ' quotes.

Comment: No the SQL file does not know about the bash variables then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to do `sudo bash`, just invoke `sudo mysql` directly and use double quotes for `$MYSQL_ROOT_PASS` on command line:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

MYSQL_ROOT_PASS='mysql'
MYSQL_APP_PASS='appSecretPass'

sudo mysql --user=root --password="$MYSQL_ROOT_PASS"<<QUERY
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '${MYSQL_ROOT_PASS}';
CREATE DATABASE appdb DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 DEFAULT COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON apdb.* to 'appuser'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '${MYSQL_APP_PASS}';
QUERY
```